# Does adding a new fragment to the backstack pause the current fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager, back-stack, fragment-lifecycle

I am currently adding a new fragment to the backstack (On top of the current fragment):

```
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.cl_my_profile_edit, newFragment)?.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction?.commit()
```

Will this pause the current fragment in which this code is run?

If this does not pause the current fragment

will calling `onPause()` as such:

```
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.cl_my_profile_edit, newFragment)?.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction?.commit()

        onPause()
```

Pause the current fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add()` does not affect any other fragment - as the name implies, it simply adds a new fragment, overlapping any existing fragments in the same container.

You can use `replace()` to replace any existing fragment, causing the other fragment to be paused, stopped, and have its view removed from the view hierarchy. This would ensure that the fragments don't visually overlap.

You cannot safely call `onPause()` or any other `on__` method - those are called by the framework, not by you.